# Combined Column Graph and Line Graph with Different Y Axis

Tags: r, graphics, charts, ggplot2, lattice

Is it possible to create a combined column graph and line graph with different Y axis like you can in Excel? I want to automate the production of graphs where the line graph is the Good -Bad ratio and the bar graph is the percent of universe for the given interval of another variable. The left Y axis would be for the Good - Bad ratio and the right Y axis would be the percent of universe. I'd like to do this with lattice but any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require(plotrix)  # followed by a slight variation of the first example of twoord.plot
twoord.plot(2:10,seq(3,7,by=0.5)+rnorm(9), type=c("bar", "l"),
   1:15,rev(60:74)+rnorm(15),xlab="Sequence",
   ylab="Ascending values",rylab="Descending values",
   main="Plot with two ordinates - points and lines")
```

There seems to be a problem with the comment formatting so I am putting the code here as well. The rx and lx vectors need to be numeric but the xticklab argument can be used to label correctly:

```
twoord.plot(lx=1:10, ly= df$Pct, rx=1:10, ry= df$Rate, type=c('bar','l'), 
xticklab=df$Segment, xlab='Segment', ylab='Percent of Good', rylab='Good Rate')
```

Comment: I think you have the right idea I'm just not going a good job of translating. I'm trying to do the following with no success.

Comment: `Segment<-c('[ 1, 12)','[12, 18)','[18, 27)','[27, 40)','[40, 54)','[54, 66)','[66, 79)','[79, 88)','[88, 93)','[93,436]')

Pct<-c(0.09419152,0.08006279,0.07535322,0.15698587,0.16797488,0.11459969,0.08006279,0.08320251,0.06593407,0.08163265)

Rate<-c(0.005, 0.0046, 0.004, 0.0087, 0.0093, 0.0061, 0.0043, 0.0043, 0.0044, 0.0045)

df<-data.frame(Segment=character(0), Pct=numeric(0), Rate=numeric(0))

df<-rbind(df,cbind(Segment, Pct, Rate))

twoord.plot(df$Segment, df$Pct, df$Segment, df$Rate, type=c('bar','l'),data=df,xlab='Segment', ylab='Percent of Good', rylab='Good Rate')`

Comment: There were some odd characters in your data but after massaging a bit I got what I think you want with:    `twoord.plot(lx=1:10, ly= df$Pct, rx=1:10, ry= df$Rate, type=c('bar','l'),    xticklab=df$Segment, xlab='Segment', ylab='Percent of Good',    rylab='Good Rate')`    Note the use of xticklab.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but I just wanted to add another option. If you find yourself in a situation where your options beyond "base" R are limited (eg if you are working on a disparate team of people and need highest possible code compatibility, a situation I've found myself in recently), you can always use the

```
par(new=TRUE)
```

command to plot one plot on top of another -- so, a barplot and a line plot. The trick here (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343776/barplot-changing-x-axe-and-adding-line)) is to use "plot" for both the line and bar charts, just use "type='h'" and the "lend" and "lwd" options to create a barplot from the line plot.

This replicates the code above, using only the "base" functions:

```
## Set up data
line.x <- 2:10
bar.x <- 2:10
bar.y <- seq(3,7,by=0.5)+rnorm(9)
bar.x <- 1:15
bar.x <- 2:10
line.x <- 1:15
line.y <- rev(60:74)+rnorm(15)
x.range <- range(bar.x, line.x)

## Plot the data
par(mar=c(5,4,4,4)+0.1)    ## Make enough room for both labels
plot(y=bar.y, x=bar.x, type='h', lwd=25, lend=4, xlim=x.range, xlab="Sequence", ylab="", main="Plot with two ordinates - points and lines")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(y=line.y, x=line.x, col='red', type='l', xlim=x.range, axes=FALSE, xlab='', ylab='')

## Set up the axes and labels
axis(side=4, col='red', labels=FALSE)
at = axTicks(4)
mtext(side = 4, text = at, at = at, col = "red", line = 1) 
## Add x-axis labels; this allows customization of the how far out labels are
mtext(text='Descending values', side=4, line=2, col='red')
mtext(text='Ascending values', side=2, line=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by hand, look at the updateusr function in the TeachingDemos package.

This only works with base graphics, not lattice.